# Variable foranea no es captada por formulario

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo esta tabla:

```
    Schema::create('fotos', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('foto');
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->date('fecha');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id'); // Foraneo a la tabla User.
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Y tengo este formulario:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header"><h1>Subir nueva imagen</h1></div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form method="POST" action="subir_foto" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            @csrf

                            <input id="user_id" type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ auth()->user()->id }}">

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="foto" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Foto</label>

                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                    <input id="foto" type="file" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('foto') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="foto" value="{{ old('foto') }}" />

                                    @if ($errors->has('foto'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('foto') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="nombre" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Nombre</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="nombre" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('nombre') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="nombre" value="{{ old('nombre') }}" placeholder="Expliqua donde la sacaste o en que consiste" required autofocus>

                                    @if ($errors->has('nombre'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('nombre') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="fecha" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Fecha en la que se creo la foto</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="fecha" type="date" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('fecha') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="fecha" value="{{ old('fecha') }}" required autofocus>

                                    @if ($errors->has('fecha'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('fecha') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Subir Foto
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Pero me sale este error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a
>   default value (SQL: insert into `fotos` (`fecha`, `nombre`, `foto`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2018-11-07, XCOM2,
>   lOy6Tw0NpryHVl7wtGSshxsipXLlN7xcom.jpg, 2018-11-07 10:17:43,
>   2018-11-07 10:17:43))

¿Que habre hecho mal?
Tengo ademas esto en Foto.php:

```
protected $fillable=['foto','nombre','fecha','user_id'];
```

Comment: ¿el campo hidden user_id tiene valor antes de mandar el formulario?

Comment: @Pepote Cuando lo pongo como text se ve que tiene el valor de la variable id del usuario.

Comment: Lo siguiente que yo haría: hacer un dump de $request->all() en el controlador para verificar que lleguen todos los datos, y repasar la creación del objeto para estar seguro que le llega el user_id.

Answer (score 2):

Ya lo he solucionado.
Resulta que al introducir la foto en la tabla, me olvide que no introducia todas las variables de golpe con `$request->all()`, sino que manualmente introducia las variables.
Lo que he hecho que quitar el "input hidden" y añadir la variable en la función para crear la fila:

```
public function sumar(FotoRequest $request){
    $foto=str_random(30).$request->file('foto')->getClientOriginalName();
    $request->file('foto')->move('archivo',$foto);
    $a=Foto::create([
        'fecha'=>$request->fecha,
        'nombre'=>$request->nombre,
        'foto'=>$foto,
        'user_id'=>auth()->user()->id
    ]);
    return back()->with('message',['success','Foto introducida con éxito. ¿Vas a subir otra foto?']);
}
```